# NetBeans, PhpStorm... Code completion for custom PHP extensions

Tags: php, netbeans, phpstorm

I have build a custom PHP extension in C and included it in php.ini. Now i would like to have a IDE which supports code completion of my custom extesnsion. i used netbeans ide but testing phpstorm at the moment. both do not show me code completion for the custom php extension :(

do i need to insert special things in my extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans uses fake php files called 'stubs' that can be included in your project (just let them sit somewhere in a place that netbeans scans.

Example for built in php functions: (See NetbeansFolder/php/phpstubs, or ctrl-click in netbeans on a native php function).

```
/**
 * (PHP 4 &gt;= 4.2.0, PHP 5)<br/>
 * Changes all keys in an array
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php
 * @param array $input <p>
 * The array to work on
 * </p>
 * @param int $case [optional] <p>
 * Either <b>CASE_UPPER</b> or
 * <b>CASE_LOWER</b> (default)
 * </p>
 * @return array an array with its keys lower or uppercased, or false if
 * <i>input</i> is not an array.
 */
function array_change_key_case (array $input, $case = 'CASE_LOWER') {}
```

Comment: okay thank you! do you know how phpstorm handles this?

edit: phpstorm handles it with stubs too. big thx!

Comment: now i have seen that phpstorm handles it with stubs, but compressed as jar files :( does anybody know how to xtend this for my custom php extension?

Comment: @viperneo Just place such stub file ANYWHERE in your project -- that's enough.

Answer (score 2):

There's a discussion about this in PhpStorm's tracker:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-174